# Why does Apache2 not respect Last-Modified headers?

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

On a  I have:

```
ProxyPass           /public !
```

in order to have content under this path served as static files directly from the file system.

But it seems that the If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match aren't used.

Request headers are always:

```
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 02 May 2022 15:18:45 GMT
If-None-Match: "1762a-5de08e8890e5e-gzip"
```

Response is always 200 with payload, and these headers:

```
Last-Modified: Mon, 02 May 2022 15:18:45 GMT
ETag: "1762a-5de08e8890e5e-gzip"
```

In this case I would expect a "304 Not Modified" response?

Surely it can not still be this 14 years old issue?
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45023

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was the above linked issue. And since Apache 2.4 mod_deflate does not support configuring the Etag behaviour, the best solution I could find was removing -gzip from the Etag:

```
RequestHeader edit "If-None-Match" '^"((.*)-gzip)"$' '"$1", "$2"'
```